# Pretend to be mysql server

Tags: mysql, proxy, redis, federated-storage-engine

For a project we are working with an several external partner. For the project we need access to their MySQL database. The problem is, they cant do that. Their databse is hosted in a managed environment where they don't have much configuration possibilities. And they dont want do give us access to all of their data. So the solution they came up with, is the federated storage engine.

We now have one table for each table of their database. The problem is, the amount of data we get is huge and will even increase in the future. That means there are a lot of inserts performed on our database. The optimal solution for us would be to intercept all incoming MySQL traffic, process it and then store it in bulk. We also thought about using someting like redis to store the data.

Additionnaly, we plan to get more data from different partners. They will potentialy provide us the data in different ways. So using redis would allow us, to have all our data in one place.

Copying the data to redis after its stored in the mysql database is not an option. We just cant handle that many inserts and we need the data as fast as possible.

TL;DR
is there a way to pretend to be a MySQL server so we can directly process data received via the federated storage engine?

---

We also thought about using the blackhole engine in combination with binary logging on our side. So incoming data would only be written to the binary log and wouldn't be stored in the database. But then performance would still be limited by Disk I/O.

Comment: I'm confused - using federated tables still requires the same access to their server. Replication will require even more access (not just some tables).

Comment: Why do you need access to their database? Can you not implement logic that allows you to access what you need of their information at run time via an API, web service, etc, hosted by them? This honestly seems like 'don't start from here'.

Comment: @Vatev the federated tables are in their database and connect ti our database. That way we dont need access to their database.

Comment: @MandyShaw sadly not. As already stated, this is the only possible solution to get access to their data. We already discussed lots of alternatives, but they dont want to give us any access to their servers. They also dont want to develop or host any additional software

Comment: Sounds as if you need to have a business level discussion re the feasibility of what you are trying to do here, frankly. 'I don't want to' is actually not going to work for them if they want to get this data flowing. Do they really have no API of any sort? What application are they using to populate this database?